# Symfony 4: Statically get container in helper class

Tags: symfony, activerecord, service, static, containers

I'm working on an active record-like system for symfony and I encountered a problem.

I have a helper class in symfony that is **not** a service, nor do I want it to become one. This class has a static property named container and a static method to set it. Now the question is, when do I call this static method to set the container?

I've tried the bundle extension, compiler pass, all to no success. (Mostly because they have to be services and when I make it a service and extend it later, it skips the compiler pass.)

Let me know if anyone requires any further information and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean it's not a service? If I understand you correctly you want to  inject the service into the container to make it available, i.e. you want a synthetic service, in terms of the Symfony DI. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/synthetic_services.html

Comment: No.. That's not what I said at all actually.

This helper class where I want the service container INSIDE is **not** a service.

So, it's just a normal class, with a static method:

`public static function set(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    self::$container = $container;
}`

Comment: I provided a more elaborate answer that is hopefully clearer. The synthetic service-approach is what the Kernel class does to create a container, make it available as part of the Kernel, but also inject itself into the container to be available as though it was a service. It seems that your definition of the term differs from what Symfony would call a service. In any case showing how you create this helper or plan to create it and how/where you use it and the container inside it will likely be helpful to get a better understanding of your problem and allow us to give a better solution.

Comment: If you insist on doing this sort of static stuff then eliminate the setContainer method and just have your class access the container directly using the global $kernel->getContainer method().  But you are heading down the wrong path and will just run into more problems down the road.  In particular,  in S4, container services are private by default and are not directly accessible via the container.

Comment: Well, I'm not planning to build facades into symfony, just the active record model. And since I wont make the container reference public on the entity I don't see how it's an anti pattern.

Comment: If you rely on the container you will rely on Symfony and you will rely on it as it is built right now. If you want to port to another framework or if Symfony fundamentally changes how it uses the container or makes services accessible in the container (which it did in Symfony 4) will affect your solution. It is safer to rely on the services you fetch from the container as it clearly limits what it depends on, without saying how they are configured. It also makes testing easier as you don't rely on a specific container setup that you can not guarantee, since it is based on your current config.

Comment: I should mention that this is not going to be used in production, it's an experiment. To, alongside other things, compare Symfony to Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject the container into the helper, i.e. call `Helper::set($ontainer)` you have to do it when the compiled container is available. Both Extension and Compiler Pass modify the container before compilation and therefore are probably not the right place, unless you want to inject the helper as a service into the container and reference the container, much like the following approach outlines.

You could call the Setter-method in your Kernel, where the container is created, or inside a Controller, which is loaded when the container is built and - when you extend the `Controller`-base class, has access to the container. I don't think that's a good idea though because you can never be certain when/if the method was called and what container is in there. Also, when using the new `AbstractController` base class you don't have access to the full container, only a service locator for the specific services needed by the controller.

When configuring it as a service inside your `services.yaml` you can use [calls or setter injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html) to inject the container service by referencing `@container`. I also wouldn't recommend this, but I consider it the lesser of the two evils, considering what you are asking.

Comment: I thought about the controller idea but that basically falls into the same problem im facing right now. I DID configure the helper class as a service and what happened was, I had to inject it first (without having to use it) before the compiler injected the container into it for me.

Also, what about using them in services? Extending the controller won't help you there. Also, can you access the kernel inside a bundle without using global?

Comment: Your helper should not rely on the container nor the Kernel. You can make the kernel global, but I have only ever seen this as a way to introduce the container into a legacy application that transitions towards Symfony where it will no longer need this global kernel. If you build something for/in Symfony I don't see a use for what you want to do. If you build something that is independent from Symfony, I see even less use for being dependent on something that is specific to Symfony.

Comment: That being said, I still only know WHAT you want to do, but not the WHY. You have to add more details to your question for me to give you a truly helpful answer for your specific use case.

Comment: I mentioned the Active Records pattern.

So, you can extend the `ActiveRecord` class, which in turn extends the earlier mentioned helper class.

The`ActiveRecord` then has access to all of the repository function and is able to execute things like `findOneBy` etc.

This makes:

`Product::findOneBy(['foo' => 'bar']);`
And things like it possible.